# Gatling JMS on IBM MQ tries to access unauthorized queue (SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE)

Tags: scala, jms, ibm-mq, gatling

I have a problem running a Gatling JMS (IBM MQ) scenario on my test environment (which I don't have admin access).
*The scenario works all fine on my own IBM queues running under docker on my own workstation.*

According to the exception, it seems it tries to access queue SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE to create a temporary queue (why does it even try to create a temporary queue in the first place?).

My scenario is a very basic **requestReply** one.

```
val MY_SCN = scenario("MY_SCN").repeat(1) {
    exec(
      jms("req MYSCN")
        .requestReply
        .queue("IN_QUEUE")
        .trackerQueue("OUT_QUEUE")
        .textMessage("Whatever message")
    )
  }
```

Here is my JMS factory setup:

```
  val ff: JmsFactoryFactory = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER)
  val cf: JmsConnectionFactory = ff.createConnectionFactory

  cf.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, MQ_HOST)
  cf.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_PORT, MQ_PORT)
  cf.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, MQ_CHANNEL)
  cf.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)
  cf.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, MQ_QM)
  cf.setStringProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)")
  cf.setBooleanProperty(JmsConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true)
  cf.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.USERID, MQ_USER)
  cf.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.PASSWORD, MQ_PASSWORD)
```

Here is my JMS config

```
  val jmsConfig = jms
    .connectionFactory(cf)
    .credentials(MQ_USER, MQ_PASSWORD)
    .messageMatcher(...)
    .usePersistentDeliveryMode
```

Here is the exception:

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
 Wrapped by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.accessTemporaryQueue(WMQConnection.java:690)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.createTemporaryDestination(WMQConnection.java:990)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createTemporaryDestination(WMQSession.java:1159)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTemporaryQueueImpl.<init>(JmsTemporaryQueueImpl.java:91)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createTemporaryQueue(JmsSessionImpl.java:1634)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createTemporaryQueue(MQSession.java:732)
    at io.gatling.jms.client.JmsConnection.destination(JmsConnection.scala:49)
    at io.gatling.jms.action.RequestReply.<init>(RequestReply.scala:53)
    at io.gatling.jms.action.RequestReplyBuilder.build(RequestReplyBuilder.scala:43)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.$anonfun$build$1(BuildAction.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build(BuildAction.scala:27)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build$(BuildAction.scala:26)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:39)
    at io.gatling.core.action.builder.LoopBuilder.build(LoopBuilder.scala:56)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.$anonfun$build$1(BuildAction.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build(BuildAction.scala:27)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build$(BuildAction.scala:26)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:51)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder.build(PopulationBuilder.scala:100)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.buildScenario(Simulation.scala:170)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.$anonfun$scenarios$1(Simulation.scala:174)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.scenarios(Simulation.scala:174)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:82)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:52)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:80)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:45)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:37)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
    at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
 Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.
 JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but IBM MQ reported an error.
 Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.accessTemporaryQueue(WMQConnection.java:690)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.createTemporaryDestination(WMQConnection.java:990)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createTemporaryDestination(WMQSession.java:1159)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTemporaryQueueImpl.<init>(JmsTemporaryQueueImpl.java:91)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createTemporaryQueue(JmsSessionImpl.java:1634)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createTemporaryQueue(MQSession.java:732)
    at io.gatling.jms.client.JmsConnection.destination(JmsConnection.scala:49)
    at io.gatling.jms.action.RequestReply.<init>(RequestReply.scala:53)
    at io.gatling.jms.action.RequestReplyBuilder.build(RequestReplyBuilder.scala:43)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.$anonfun$build$1(BuildAction.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build(BuildAction.scala:27)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build$(BuildAction.scala:26)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:39)
    at io.gatling.core.action.builder.LoopBuilder.build(LoopBuilder.scala:56)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.$anonfun$build$1(BuildAction.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build(BuildAction.scala:27)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build$(BuildAction.scala:26)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:51)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder.build(PopulationBuilder.scala:100)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.buildScenario(Simulation.scala:170)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.$anonfun$scenarios$1(Simulation.scala:174)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.scenarios(Simulation.scala:174)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run0(Runner.scala:82)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:52)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:80)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:45)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:37)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
    ... 6 more
 Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Are you sure that on your docker queue manager it was not creating a temporary model queue?  What permissions does the app user have on your docker queue manager.

Comment: Actually I think it did create temporary queues. 
But since my app user has admin access on the MQ run in docker there is no porblem. 
This was just an FYI to inform people that the scenario runs otherwise

Comment: I would suggest figuring out how to provide a specific reply queue,  it seems by default the app framework you are using is trying a TDQ.

Comment: Ok, there is a reply queue option indeed. I will try to specify it and check if it works.

Comment: Oh my god, it does work, thank you so much.

If anybody runs in that problem, just add a replyQueue to your scenario.

val MY_SCN = scenario("MY_SCN").repeat(1) {
    exec(
      jms("req MYSCN")
        .requestReply
        .queue("IN_QUEUE")
        .replyQueue("OUT_QUEUE")
        .trackerQueue("OUT_QUEUE")
        .textMessage("Whatever message")
    )
  }

Comment: Heyjogo, I suggest you take your last comment and add a self answer to this question unless you want me to provide a more general answer like I did above and then provide the example you show above in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I had never heard about Gatling JMS. Something new to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JoshMc for the hint.
Here is the fix:

```
val MY_SCN = scenario("MY_SCN").repeat(1) {
    exec(
      jms("req MYSCN")
        .requestReply
        .queue("IN_QUEUE")
        .replyQueue("OUT_QUEUE")
        .trackerQueue("OUT_QUEUE")
        .textMessage("Whatever message")
    )
  }
```